# HTML Media Capture API vs. getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

currently, I'm trying to do some really simple thing (well, actually I thought it is simple...): **I want to take a photo from the web-cam in a web-application**.

I stumbled over two possibilities:

**1. The HTML Media Capture API which looks really easy:**

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

**2. JavaScript media streams, which also look pretty easy:**

```
navigator.getUserMedia()
```

And here comes my question:

The HTML Media Capture API is not working in desktop browsers and the JavaScript media streams are not working on iOS. So which one should I take? Both? Which one will be developed in the future? Which one is the preferred way? Which one do you prefer? Are there any drawbacks in one solutions that I don't see so fare (except of the compatibility?).

Thanks.

BTW: I'm not an experienced HTML/JavaScript developer, so please be kind ;)

Comment: this is cutting edge stuff ... here are 2 good posts that will get you started http://html5doctor.com/getusermedia/ and http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera (too much info to re-post here -- sorry link frowners).

Comment: I'd say both... the simplest concept would be to use Modernizr or other feature detection, have the input, and if the input will not work natively then trigger the javascript version.  That's the standard way of dealing with all progressive enhancement though, so nothing new here just cuz these elements/apis' are new.

Answer (score 3):

**Mobile browsers**

Use HTML Media Capture to capture an image *directly* from the camera:

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture >`

Android (3.0+) will jump straight to the camera. Here's how it will look after some CSS styling:

[image: Pipe Video Recorder on Android]

iOS (6-10) will still give you the option to select an existing photo since it doesn't support `capture`. See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) for details.

**Desktop browsers**:

1. Access the webcam: use MediaStream API's `getUserMedia`:

`navigator.getUserMedia` or the newer promise based `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

2. Use the canvas to take a snapshot

[David Walsh's example](https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera) covers both steps on desktop.

Answer (score 2):

here is example 
http://html5.by/blog/demo/image-capture-getusermedia/
and here is article that can help you
http://html5.by/blog/html5-image-capture-getusermedia-stream-api-mirror/
sorry it is in Russian, but example is working and you can check the code
+ google translate :)

hope it will help