# HTML Media Capture on desktop browsers

Tags: browser, getusermedia, polyfills

Does anyone know, if any desktop browser has support of HTML Media Capture? Maybe beta versions, or with experimental flag, or dev build?

Or maybe there is a polyfill for this functionality using getUserMedia?

I need it for POC, so I'm interested in any easy solution/workaround.

Comment: See this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Media Capture API vs. getUserMedia()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338937/html-media-capture-api-vs-getusermedia/17581086#17581086) seems to point to a getUserMedia equivalent of HTML Media Capture for desktop browsers